# iAds causes problems with auto layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

Whenever I set

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

in my viewDidLoad method, my layouts all get shifted over and messed up for some reason. The webview has been zoomed in by a few pixels and the status bar is shifted down.

[image]

**but when I remove that line of code, my ad displays just fine and everything is perfect.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're implementing your own `ADBannerView` then you need to remove `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` from your `viewDidLoad`.

`self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a no hassle way of implementing iAd banners in your application. This will create an `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network.

You either implement your own `ADBannerView` or use `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true`, not both.

Comment: That's a great explanation. Thank you