# Making iAd Banner Not Affect Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I have created an iAd banner using the main storyboard. Can I make it so it does not affect the other elements to the app? e.g. not resizing the display when the ad is loaded?

Comment: I have used iAd before, and it does not affect the way the other elements in the main storyboard are, at least in my app. iAd has its own placeholder so it'll be there, and it only pops up once the add is clicked, so it shouldn't modify the way your app looks. Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Check my answer here: [iAds causes problems with auto layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420273/iads-causes-problems-with-auto-layout)

Comment: Daniel - Worked, thanks!